# Docker: bash terminal starts without prompt

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, docker

I have a simple container that looks like this:

```
FROM devbox/rails3.2.1

RUN apt-get install -y -q libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y -q libqtwebkit-dev
EXPOSE 3000
CMD /bin/bash
```

where devbox/rails3.2.1 is a container I made that starts with 'FROM ubuntu' and installs Ruby on Rails. This is a running in a Vagrant Virtual Box VM using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS. When I run this using:

```
 docker run -t -i -name myapp -p 3000:3000 -v /src/myapp:/src/myapp -link myappsql:myappsql devbox/myapp
```

The container starts, but my terminal shows a blank line with no prompt and typing doesn't do anything. If I run docker ps I can see that the container is running. Even stranger, If I open a second terminal and run 'docker attach myapp' I get a functioning terminal (though I have to press enter first) and if I switch back to my first terminal and type, the output appears in my second terminal!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any ENTRYPOINT in "devbox/rails3.2.1"?

Comment: No. It ends with CMD bash

Comment: Do you have a .bashrc etc in your home dir? May need to find a setting for `PROMPT`. Good luck.

Comment: Did you try `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That all sounds like expected functionality. 
When doing the "docker run" command put the "/bin/bash" in it to immediately have the bash available to you without having to attach first.

```
docker run -t -i -name myapp -p 3000:3000 -v /src/myapp:/src/myapp -link myappsql:myappsql devbox/myapp /bin/bash
```